# Import Data From Website Database

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

What I am Trying to do is import data into excel from a web query.  The problem that i face is that the ip address (ex. 10.10.111.20) only shows page 1 with only 20 rows of entry data.  i can click page2 and it show the page2 and so on.  what i am trying to do is either select all pages and export all data into excel or create a unique url

> http://10.10.111.20/?javascript:_doPostBack('GridView1','Page$2')<

I was having no luck it would just show still the 1st page

Answer (score 0):

Inspect that link for "next page" or "page 2", what is behind it, what does it link to?  With any luck it uses GET, and you will have the URL that you need to use to get each page.

Comment: do you mean check the source code from the page.. I will try, if you could i can forward you the actual IP address, i just did not want to post it publicly